# Change favicon based on environment (dev, stage, or prod) in React

Tags: html, reactjs, environment-variables, favicon

I'm attempting to change favicons based on environments so that users know if they are on `dev`, `stage`, or `prod`.

Tutorials such as [this one](https://reactgo.com/react-change-favicon-dynamically/) and [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-favicon-dynamically/) usually show how to change favicons based on button push callbacks, and not by accessing `env` variables.

The [react docs on custom env variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) make it seem like this is achievable, but I'm not sure how to access the `env` variables in the `index.html` properly to  conditionally change my favicon.

Below is my current attempt

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon.svg" id="favicon" />
 ...
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <script>

    //returns Uncaught ReferenceError: REACT_APP_APP_ENV is not defined
    console.log(REACT_APP_APP_ENV);
    //returns nothing
    console.log(PUBLIC_URL);
    //returns nothing
    console.log(process.REACT_APP_APP_ENV === 'dev' ? 'yep!' : 'nope!');
    //returns nothing
    console.log(process.PUBLIC_URL)

    const getFaviconEl = () => {
      return document.getElementById("favicon");
    }

    const getFaviconByEnv = (env) => {
      const favicon = getFaviconEl();
      switch (env) {
        case 'dev':
          favicon.href = "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon.svg"
        case 'prod':
          favicon.href = "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon-prod.svg"
        case 'stage':
          favicon.href = "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon-stage.svg"
        default:
          "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon.svg";
      }
    };
    getFaviconByEnv(process.REACT_APP_APP_ENV)
  </script>
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I achieved it:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
   //href left blank; will be dynamically generated based on env 
  <link rel="icon" href="" id="favicon" />
 ...
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <script>
    const getFaviconEl = () => {
      return document.getElementById("favicon");
    }
    const getFaviconByEnv = (env) => {
      const favicon = getFaviconEl();

      switch (env) {
        //icons files public directory accessed with %PUBLIC_URL% prefix
        case 'prod':
          return favicon.href = "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon-prod.svg";
        case 'stage':
          return favicon.href = "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon-stage.svg";
        default:
        return favicon.href = "%PUBLIC_URL%/app-icon-dev.svg";
      }
    };
    //defined in .env file, where, in my case, the env names are changed to 'dev', 'stage', 'prod', or 'local'
    getFaviconByEnv('%REACT_APP_SOME_ENV_VARIABLE_DEFINED_IN_.ENV%')
  </script>
 ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

##### React specific Solution

As you mentioned in your question, React has a neat feature that is [Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/),

These environment variables can be useful for displaying information conditionally based on where the project is deployed or consuming sensitive data that lives outside of version control.

You can actually define a variable in env file and reference that in your title like so:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href={proccess.env.REACT_APP_MY_FAVICON_URL}>
```

you can also change the title of your site using this method:

```
<title>%REACT_APP_WEBSITE_NAME%</title>
```

This way you can define different titles for different envs like `env.local`, `env.production` e.t.c

##### General Solution

***this solution assumes your develop and production urls are different***

You can use the following logic:

let's say this is your favicon tag:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

to change it based on your env, use this in your JS:

```
if (location.hostname === "localhost" 
 || location.hostname === "127.0.0.1" 
 || location.hostname.search("local") != -1) {
    $("link[rel=icon]").attr("href", "favicon_dev.png");
} else {
    $("link[rel=icon]").attr("href", "favicon.png");
}
```

**Note**: the following test `location.hostname.search("local") != -1` matches the local aliases like http://mywebsite.com.local. If you have troubles with this - read [this](http://strawberrycode.com/blog/alias-localhost/).
you can also just get the URL using `window.location.href` and condition by it

Comment: can you please add some context to your snippet please?  where would I put that?  Also, is the path I started down totally incorrect or illogical?

Comment: I'm sorry mate! I'm editing my answer right now :)

Comment: I've changed it completely. hope it helps

Comment: What JS file does this go in? I can't add it to index.html.